# How do I put a text element below a absolute div?

Tags: html, css

(edited) My body's width is 1080px, but I'm trying to make a div that takes 100% width of the viewport which is larger than the body's width, for doing that I must use `position: absolute;` on it.
But now I'm trying to put a line of text below that absolute div, but whatever I do it just will keep going above it, I've tried many ways but I couldn't fix it, please help.
Here is my code:

```css
body {
  width: 1080px;
}

.div {
  background: #f5f5f4;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 500px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<p>text</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes that will be at the top keep that in different div and make that to absolute and then keep one div inside where you will apply the same property and but not absolute and then keep paragraph there

Comment: Why would you need `position: absolute;` for making a div that is full width with another background color? By using this you are fixing the position of your div element. Remove that line and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED) Actually I think I know what you mean now, do you want the width to be `width: 100vw` (100 of the viewports' width) and make the body `overflow-x: visible` if you want the div to be larger than the body width

```css
body {
  width: 1080px;
  overflow-x: visible
}

.div {
  background: #f5f5f4;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for answering but this will makes the div have a only 1080p width, I want the width of that div be full page from left to right. Maybe it's because I didn't described well so you've missunderstand, and if so I apologize for that.

Comment: Toby: Yes I have, but that wouldn't make the div's width go beyond body's width. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Actually I think I know what you mean now, do you want the width to be `width: 100vw` (100 of the viewports' width) and make the body `overflow-x: visible` if you want the div to be larger than the body width.

Comment: I edited my answer with that solution! Click "full page" to see it work!

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant! Sorry for I couldn't describe it better because I'm new to coding. I added these two lines to my code, I saw there is still some white space in the left of the viewport, do I need to add any other codes to make them invisible? Thanks again!

Comment: So... you can add `margin: 0` to body to fix this, but I think this is all a bad way to just make the width of the text less than that of the body for a few reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much Toby! this might have be a bad way but I will use this as a solution for now, since I don't want to take more of your time and they says better to avoid extended discussions in comments. Turely thanks for everything!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209554/discussion-between-toby56-and-yukiteru).

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  width: 1080px;
}

.div {
  background: #f5f5f4;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 500px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but this will makes the div have a only 1080p width, I want the width of that div be full page from left to right. Maybe it's because I didn't described well so you've missunderstand, and if so I apologize for that.

Comment: You can use width:100%  for div.

Answer (score 0):

On the text class add the following css

```
    position: relative;
    top: 600px;
```

or you want something else?